# SML, Write a function that concatenates a list of lists

Tags: list, concatenation, sml

I need to write a concat function in StandardML such that:

```
concat [[5,4,3],[],[9,5],[],[],[1,1]] = [5,4,3,9,5,1,1]
```

I am new at SML, so I don't think I fully understand how to breakdown the lists and append them.  The answer may use the built in append function

```
aList @ bList
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're expected to write such a function, I'm assuming you have learned how to build recursive functions that iterate through a list. That knowledge plus the `@` function should be enough.

If you're unsure about which list method to use, `listA @ listB` creates a new list from the combination of listA and listB, while `item1 :: listA` creates a new list with `item1` added to the head of `listA`.